# Почему adb connect не работает на мотороллах, но работает на остальных устройствах?

Tags: bat, adb, android-adb

У меня есть 5 смартфонов. Две разные мотороллы, два нексуса и хромбук. Для каждого устройства я создал свой bat-файл для подключения устройства через wi-fi, используя команду **adb connect**. При этом коннект успешно работает для трех устройств, которые не мотороллы, но не работает для моторолл. При выполнении скрипта я мобильные устройства не подключаю к ПК. Теоретически должно работать и так (по крайней мере для трех устройств работает). При выполнении скрипта на мотороллах получаю ошибку:

> C:\Users\lll\Desktop>adb connect 192.168.0.107:5555 unable to connect to 192.168.0.107:5555: cannot connect to 192.168.0.107:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)

Режим разработки и отладка по USB включена везде.

Еще одна странность, что на мотороллах все-же возможно успешно выполнить коннекшн по безпроводу, но нужно сначала приконнектиться по USB, и выполнить скрипт - и то срабатывает только со второй попытки.

Вот сам скрипт:

```
adb disconnect 192.168.0.100:5555
adb disconnect 192.168.0.101:5555
adb disconnect 192.168.0.102:5555
adb disconnect 192.168.0.103:5555
adb disconnect 192.168.0.104:5555
adb disconnect 192.168.0.105:5555
adb disconnect 192.168.0.106:5555
adb disconnect 192.168.0.107:5555
adb disconnect 192.168.0.108:5555
adb disconnect 192.168.0.109:5555
adb disconnect 192.168.0.110:5555
@adb kill-server
@adb start-server
@adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.0.107:5555
adb devices
pause
```

Хотя я не уверен, что **kill-server**, **start-server** и **tcpip** нужны в данном случае. Но по крайней мере на остальных устройствах коннекшн работает.

Что я делаю не так? Я хочу заставить мотороллы тоже подключаться по безпроводу без предварительного подключения устройства по USB.